Cohomology class of automorphism group of Galois form
Let $\Gamma$ be the Galois group of a finite Galois extension $K/k$ of fields of characteristic zero. Let $G$ be an algebraic group defined over $k$. Let $G'$ be another algebraic group over $k$. We say that $G'$ is a $K/k$-form of $G$ if $G_K$ and $G'_K$ are isomorphic. It is well-known that the $K/k$-forms of $G$ are in natural bijection with the pointed Galois cohomology set $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut}G(K))$. The trivial cohomology class corresponds to $G$ itself.
Now consider the automorphism group schemes $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(G')$. The latter is clearly a $K/k$-form of the former, so both correspond to classes in $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut(Aut} G(K)))$. What is the cohomology class of $\operatorname{Aut}(G')$?
I assume that it arises as the image of the class of $G'$ in $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut}G(K))$ along the map induced by conjugation $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, but I'm not quite sure. Can we characterise those forms of $G$ which map to zero under this map of cohomology groups?
